# Multiple multipartfile upload testing in grails

Tags: grails, gsp, spock

I'm trying to write a test for file uploading in grails. I'm using spock as my testing framework.

I have a javascript function that link to a button on my view that adds an `<input type="file">` to my form whenever it is clicked.

It looks something like this:

```
<script>
        var fileNum = 1;
        function addUploader() {
            fileNum++;
            var fileInputTag = "<input type=\"file\" name=\"myfile." +fileNum+ "\"/>";
            var uploadField = document.getElementById("uploadFields");
            var row = uploadField.insertRow(fileNum + 1);
            var cell = row.insertCell(0);
            cell.innerHTML = fileInputTag + "<br/>";
        }
    </script>

<tr>
  <td>
    <input type="file" class="required" name="myfile.1" />
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <a href="#" onCLick="addUploader()" onSubmit="return false">More Files</a> <br />
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Download"/>
  </td>
</tr>
```

My controller looks something like this:

```
def uploadFile(){
    List<MultipartFile> files = []
    params.myfile.each {
        if (it.value.isEmpty()) {
            flash.message = message(code: 'upload.empty.message')
            redirect(uri: "/")
            return
        }
        files.add((MultipartFile) it.value)
    }
    def faxPreviews = []
    faxPreviews = uploadFileService.generateFaxPreviews(files)
render(view:'/uploadfile/index', model:[p:uploadFileService.decodeFaxPreviews(faxPreviews)])
}
```

I want to test that a flash message is shown if the list is empty but I don't know how to put that in the test. I've been trying to search how to mock the view params in the test but so far no go.

Answer (score 0):

This was actually very easy. D'oh! I ended up with this test.

```
void "updloadFile should warn when no files are attached."() {
    given:
        def file = new GrailsMockMultipartFile('mockFile', ''.bytes)
        Map<MultipartFile> files = [:]
        files[1] = file
        controller.params.myfile = files

    when:
        controller.uploadFile()

    then:
        response.redirectedUrl == '/'
        flash.message != null
}
```

My problem was that I thought the myfile in the view was a key when it is actually the name of a map. So myfile.1 would turn into a myfile[1] = "whatever value is passed to input"